# What does the notation $[,]$, $\{,\}$ in the Clifford algebra mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras

From Charbonneau, Harland: Deformations of nearly Kähler instantons:

[image: Identities on Clifford algebra with symbols [,] and {,}]

It is explained in the previous paragraph that the authors use the canonical identification $\operatorname{Cl}(V,g)=\Lambda^*V$.

> Question:
>   What do the symbols $[,]$, $\{,\}$, and $\lrcorner$ mean?

I guess that $\alpha \lrcorner \beta$ means interior product of the vector $\alpha* \in V$ and $\beta$, where $\alpha*$ is defined via the bilinear form on $V$.
I further thought that $[\alpha,\beta]$ might mean $\alpha \beta- \beta \alpha$ (multiplication in the Clifford algebra), but then the first claim isn't true.

For $\{,\}$ I have no clue what it could mean.

Comment: I would bet {a,b}=ab+ba which is the anti-commutator (although I haven’t read this book)

Comment: @Greg.Paul Could very well be the case. In the case "$p$ even" this is correct. In the case "$p$ odd" your expression is still a $(p+1)$-form, but the lemma I cited gives the $(p-1)$-form $2 \alpha \lrcorner \beta$, so it doesn't seem to be right. Or maybe my guess for $\lrcorner$ is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols mean:

- $[\alpha,\beta]=\alpha \beta - \beta \alpha$
- $\{ \alpha,\beta \} = \alpha \beta + \beta \alpha$
- $\alpha \lrcorner \beta = \alpha^\# \lrcorner \beta$, where $\alpha ^\#$ denotes the dual vector of $\alpha$ with respect to the metric $g$ on $V$

The notation $\lrcorner$ appears in this context in Baum, Friedrich: Twistor and Killing spinors on Riemannian manifolds, p.15.
(It is not used in exactly the same way there, but it strongly suggests that the interpretation given above is correct)
$[,]$ and $\{,\}$ follows from this.
As an example, check $[e_1,e_1e_2]=e_1e_1e_2-e_1e_2e_1=2e_2=2 e_1 \lrcorner e_1e_2$.